# AlpineJs x-for directive gets updated when another property gets updated

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am completely re-editing this, as it has grown in complexity. Let me explain it with a simpler reproducible scenario: https://codepen.io/ozeru/pen/oNEQYpd

```
<div x-data="{hasValue: false, categories: [{label: 'hey', id: 'first'}, {label: 'yow', id: 'second'}], htmlTest:'<input type=\'checkbox\'>'}">
```

```
<template x-for="(category, index) in categories">
      <div>
        <div x-html="htmlTest">
        </div>
        <label class="c-system-tile" x-bind:for="category.id">
          <span class="hello" x-text="category.label"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </template>
```

In the code, if you check the checkbox, and then click on test, you will see that the checkbox will loose its state.

The reason for that is, clicking on test means that the hasValue property gets updated. This update, triggers a COMPLETE re-evaluation of the all the bindings we have. So anything put in the x-html just plainly gets re-added causing all kinds of other troubles for us (in this case, a simple checkbox state, but can be different things.)

My question is, is this normal? Is this how alpinejs works? Or are there ways to circumvent this? Seems like its a bug or something, to update all bindings because some random property gets updated?

Edit: I am accepting the answer of this question, as the comments contain the solution. Its a V2 problem, need to update to V3.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an unique `key` attribute to the for-loop, so Alpine.js can track its items:

```
<template x-for="category in categories" x-bind:key="\`systemCategory-\${category.id}\`">
```

Furthermore instead of `x-on:click="selectCategory(category.key)"` on the labels, you can use `x-model` on the radio buttons and use a `$watch` to respond to category changing.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't resolve the issue. Adding a unique key does nothing in this case. Any other property being updated, re-renders my entire x-for loop'ed templates. Is this expected behaviour from alpinejs?

Comment: If it re-renders the loop it should keep its state at least. Maybe its a bug fixed in v3? Another guess: I noticed that the origin of your data is a different object. Maybe if you alter that, Alpine.js wrongly tries to re-render each child property where you used that object. Could you provide an example dataset that reproduces the problem?

Comment: See original question for the edited codepen for a certain reproduced scenario

Comment: Ok, now I see the problem. You are using data binding wrongly, currently there's no connection between the radio input's state/value and the Alpine.js data. You are using radio input as a simple button with one way data flow. Please refactor your code like I suggested in my answer using [`x-model`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/model#radio-inputs) on the radio buttons (as well as the `:key` attribute on the loop), so Alpine.js can provide two way data binding, as you expected. You can skip `x-on:click="selectCategory(category.key)"`.

Comment: No, sorry, you are missing the point. Perhaps I'm not explaining it properly. If you check a simplified codepen here: https://codepen.io/ozeru/pen/oNEQYpd If you select a checkbox, and click on test, it will toggle the hasValue property. But, by doing so, it rerenders my entire html binding. Causing me to lose the input checked state as well. Forcing me to indeed, as you say, keep in a x-model binding. But thats one solution to many problems we potentially can have, if the entire x-html binding gets refreshed, due to a random property that has nothing to do with it?

Comment: Right, I think this behavior is a shortcoming of v2. When I replaced v2 with v3 in your codepen, it was working fine, keeping the state of the checkboxes (however, it's still recommended to use x-model). The v3 branch uses Vue.js' reactivity, which is more advanced. If you can, migrate your code to v3 branch.